# How to listen to a Geofence BroadcastReceiver in an Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I've followed [Android's tutorial on adding a Geofence with a BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#HandleGeofenceTransitions).

This successfully sends me a notification on geofence transitions.

However I now need to receive the broadcast in my Fragment/Activity as well so I can perform some UI changes.

Below is my current code registering the geofence broadcast:

**MapFragment.kt**

```
private fun createOnlineGeofence(currentLocation: GeoPoint){
    val geofenceId = "ONLINE_GEOFENCE_ID"
    with(sharedPref.edit()) {
        putString("geofenceId", geofenceId)
        apply()
    }
    /** Create Geofence */
    user.geofence = Geofence.Builder().apply {
        setRequestId(geofenceId)
            setCircularRegion(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude, 400f)
            setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
            setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
            setNotificationResponsiveness(300000)
    }.build()
    val geofenceRequest = GeofencingRequest.Builder().apply {
        addGeofence(user.geofence)
    }.build()
    val pendingIntent: PendingIntent by lazy {
        val intent = Intent(mContext.applicationContext, GeofenceBroadcastReceiverTesting::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("type", "online")
        intent.putExtra("geofenceId", geofenceId)
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Created online Geofence, geofenceId: ${user.geofence?.requestId}")
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        geofencingClient.addGeofences(geofenceRequest, pendingIntent)?.run {
            addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d(TAG, "Online geofence added")
            }
            addOnFailureListener {
                exception -> Log.d(TAG, "Exception: $exception")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I listen to the Geofence transitions inside my Fragment/Activity?

Comment: You can dynamically instantiate and register/unregister a receiver (`GeofenceBroadcastReceiverTesting`) in your Activity by calling `registerReceiver(/*yourReceiverInstance*/)` in `onStart()` (or `onCreate()`) and `unregisterReceiver(/*yourReceiverInstance*/)` in `onStop()` (or `onDestroy()`). check  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#context-registered-receivers

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34756416/4253952) using LocalBroadcastManager (LBM). The idea is to tell the LBM that you want to hear broadcasts for a certain IntentFilter & in the Geofence BroadcastReceiver, you can call LBM to send the broadcast for the Activity to receive. It goes without saying that you would have to implement a BroadcastReceiver in the Activity itself to accept the local broadcast.